# How to make a <col> overrule a <tr> background color?

Tags: html, css

If I make even rows red and the second column blue, the intersections become red.

I'm trying to make the whole second column blue.

```css
tr:nth-of-type(2n)
{
  background: red;
}
col:nth-of-type(2)
{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Make <s>cell 17</s> the whole second column blue</h1>
<p>Even if the table has 9999 other rows, which have cells with random rowspans...</p>

<table>
  
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  
  <tr><td>1<td rowspan="3">2<td>3<td rowspan="2">4<td>5
  <tr><td>6<td>8<td rowspan="2">10
  <tr><td>11<td>13<td>14
  <tr><td>16<td rowspan="2">17<td>18<td>19<td>20
  <tr><td>21<td>23<td>24<td>25
    
</table>
```

Comment: Whole second column `blue` right.. I think you have a typo in the question

Comment: Sorry, fixed...

Comment: Also your `tr` and `td` tags doesn't have a closing tags..

Comment: @RajshekarReddy closing tags are optional for `tr` and `td` in HTML5

Comment: @ZoltanToth thanks for the information, was not aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

**ANSWER UPDATED**

You can target `td[rowspan]` to ensure that all rowspans get a background-color. See updated snippet.

```css
tr:nth-of-type(2n)
{
  background: red;
}

td[rowspan] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Make <s>cell 17</s> the whole second column blue</h1>
<p>Even if the table has 9999 other rows, which have cells with random rowspans...</p>

<table>
  
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  
  <tr><td>1<td rowspan="3">2<td>3<td>4<td>5
  <tr><td>6<td>8<td>9<td>10
  <tr><td>11<td>13<td>14<td>15
  <tr><td>16<td rowspan="2">17<td>18<td>19<td>20
  <tr><td>21<td>23<td>24<td>25
    
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't change the table structure, just the style.

Comment: @TamásBolvári   OK, I've updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution has a serious side effect: every cell becomes blue which has a `rowspan` attribute, even if it is not in the second column. My goal is to make the whole second column blue, without making anything else blue. _Even if the table has 9999 other rows, which have cells with random rowspans..._ I'll clarify the question, sorry if it was ambiguous.

Comment: Good point... Answer by GCyrillus looks better for your situation

Answer (score 2):

best is to select `td` instead `tr` and filter `td[rowspan]`.

background `col` will always be drawn behind `tr`/`td`/`th` anyhow.

example:

```css
tr:nth-of-type(2n) td:not([rowspan])/* if selector do not match, then no background*/
{
  background: red;
}
col:nth-of-type(2)
{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Make <s>cell 17</s> the whole second column blue</h1>
<p>Even if the table has 9999 other rows, which have cells with random rowspans...</p>

<table>

  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>

  <tr>
    <td>1
      <td rowspan="3">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td rowspan="2">17
      <td>18</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24
      <td>25</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```